# Oozie actionData not available on Error

Tags: hadoop, scheduled-tasks, oozie, oozie-coordinator, bigdata

I have a oozie job as follows:

```
<action name="action1">
    <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
        <host>${sshHost}</host>
        <command>${scriptDir}/${scriptName}</command>
        <capture-output/>
    </ssh>
    <ok to="scheduleOkAction" />
    <error to="scheduleErrorAction" />
</action>
<action name="action2">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${emailToAddress}</to>
        <subject>Workflow failed to run</subject>
        <body>
          [Workflow - ${wf:name()}] failed to run.
          Stack Trace
          ${wf:actionData('action1')['ERROR']}
        </body>
    </email>
    <ok to="kill" />
    <error to="kill" />
</action>
<action name="action3">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${emailToAddress}</to>
        <subject>Success</subject>
        <body>
          [Workflow - ${wf:name()}] - OK.
          ${wf:actionData('action1')['SUCCESS_CODE']}
        </body>
    </email>
    <ok to="kill" />
    <error to="kill" />
</action>
```

When 'action1' run with out an exception, the workflow takes me to 'action3' and sends me an email **with** the 'SUCCESS_CODE' actionData. But when 'action1' throws an exception, the workflow takes me to 'action2' and sends me an email **with out** 'ERROR' actionData.

Is it a valid behavior to loose all actionData in an event of error in Oozie? Or am I missing something?

Comment: what are you getting in mail in case of error. If you have hue please also check output data of `action1` in case of error.  Also in ssh `action1` are you doing `try/catch` properly so that stack trace is properly captured there, please check by printing in `action1` itself.

Comment: @abhiieor in case of error I am getting the following mail:
   
    **[Workflow - action1] failed to run.
    Stack Trace**

     I don't see any 'ERROR' actionData.
     I have done the try catch properly to capture the stack trace and print    it out in the standard output. I can see the print statement in the oozie logs:
oozie-oozi/OOZIE_JOB_ID/action1--ssh/log@0.stdout

Comment: Is this the right way to obtain stack trace from an Action in Oozie. Or is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: @bitan: Yet another method to get error logs is to actually look at the Hadoop Map Reduce job which is created by oozie. There will be a pointer to that job in the corresponding action's URL on oozie UI. 

Additionally, can you also describe the script in action1. It will definitely assist in debugging